# window.onload function - how to make it ignore google ads?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make the window.onload function ignore a pages google ads?
If certain ads on the page take a while to load (such as video ads etc..) the function will not fire.

**example..**

```
function pageLoaded() {
        alert('Loaded');
}
window.onload = pageLoaded;
```

No alert box will appear until all ads are completely loaded..

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
pageLoaded();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: what? how would that help me?

Comment: @user1483508 it would fire `pageLoaded()` before ads and videos are fully loaded but all elements can be used. If you are using jQuery, you can do the same with `$(document).ready()`

Comment: oh thanks, didnt realise, thought even that would wait until ads were finished loading.. :)

Comment: @user1483508 ah, in that case you are not in control of it because the ads are probably not letting the browser proceed until they are ready. `$(document).ready` would not wait for images, videos etc normally.